# kernel 2.6.35.3 - how to convert .config to defconfig

Tags: linux-kernel, configuration, make

If you have newer kernel (i.e. > 2.6.35.3) you can create a 'defconfig' from a '.config' by using

> make savedefconfig

But in kernel 2.6.35.3 - does not provide you with 'savedefconfig' target.

How to create a defconfig from .config in kernel 2.6.35.3?